# Removing escape character

Tags: java

I am facing a weird file reading a file. The problem is when I read a file, it displays all the data in one line. To heal this, I added line.separators while reading the file. It works fine.see **following code**

```
line = br.readLine();
                while (line != null) {
                    String[] parts = line.split(" ");
                    word_count += parts.length;
                    line_count++;
                    fileRead+=line;
                    fileRead+=System.getProperty("line.separator","\n");
                    line = br.readLine();
              }
```

Now, the problem comes, when I read the data from fileRead String and count the length of each and every word, then it doesn't give me the correct length/size of some strings like

Let say file contains

> Hello, today is Sunday
>
> Thanks

It gives me correct lenth of hello(5) today (5) is(2) Sunday(13). it appends Sunday  string like Sunday/n/rThanks. I dont know to get the length of two individuals strings

**Code for getting lengths**

```
public void stringLenth(String[] parts) {
        for(int i=0;i<parts.length;i++){
            System.out.println("hello"+parts[i]+"lenth"+parts[i].trim().length());
            parts[i]  = parts[i].replaceAll("\\r|\\n", "");
            if(parts[i].length() < minWordCount  ){
                minWordCount = parts[i].trim().length();
            }
        }
    }
```

Any idea?

Comment: Remove the second \ symbol from the **replaceAll** function and split removal for CR and LF - then it will work correctly! => replaceAll("\r", "").replaceAll("\n", "");

Answer (score 0):

Use `\\s` instead of a single whitespace character to split your line.

Instead of splitting, try to use a regex with a `Matcher` and use `\\w` as regex to find all words.